# PHP - Single checkbox validation - validates but even when checked, won't submit.

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

Im writing code for form validation in PHP, but i've got a problem with checkbox validation. 
When going through the form, if you don't check the checkbox, it will give the correct error message.

However even if you do check the checkbox, it still gives the same error message.

Here is the code so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $errors = array(); 

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($firstname)) {
        $errors[] = 'First name can\'t be empty'; 
    }

    if (empty($lastname)) {
        $errors[] = 'Last name can\'t be empty'; 
    }

    if (empty($address)) {
        $errors[] = 'Address can\'t be empty';
    }

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email'; 
    }

    if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Password can\'t be empty'; 
    }

}

if (!isset($checkbox)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please agree to the privacy policy';
} 

$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

$_SESSION['validerrors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['sex'] = $sex;
$_SESSION['age'] = $age; 
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
$_SESSION['checkbox'] = $checkbox;

if (!empty($errors)) {
    header('Location: index.php'); 
} else { 
    header('Location: writevalues.php'); 
}
```

Everything else in the above code is working fine but i haven't been able to find any helpful answers to the checkbox validation situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're checking if `$checkbox` isn't set before you assign it

Comment: Add `exit();` after __ALL__ header locations. (you may also want to unset `$_SESSION['validerrors']` at the end of `index.php` otherwise another page could show those errors too!)

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

@Waygood - Added all that into this page and the others, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling this code:

```
if (!isset($checkbox)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please agree to the privacy policy';
}
```

before this line:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

So of course `isset($checkbox)` is going to return `false` because its not set at that point!

You could just change that if statement to:

```
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){ ...
```

Or move the line `$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];` above that if statement.

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel like an idiot now! I'll make sure to set the answer after the 10 minutes is up!